# Why is Django sending me Invalid HTTP_HOST header with my server IP?

Tags: django, logging, nginx

So Django is sending me mail with this info:

```
[Django] ERROR: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '<my server IP here>'.You may need to add u'<my server IP here>' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

No stack trace available

Request repr() unavailable.
```

The problem is... You can't access my website with the server IP because I only allowing domain that already is in the ALLOWED_HOST setting.

So... What should I do?

Edit: I am using Nginx -> Gunicorn. This error only happens sometimes, like 1-2 times per week.

Comment: Probably because you didn't set the header before proxying to django, please add your virtual host config file and describe your server structure if it has anything special.

Comment: This is not happening very often, so it's hard to find the reason for the error message. Anywat, I am using Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Django

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the reason.

It was when someone tried to access the server via IP over HTTPS, as in https:// (and the server-ip)

The solution is to disable that option.

Solution for Nginx:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/example.key;
    return      444;
}
```

Comment: This is happening to me to. How did you disable it?

Comment: It depends on what web server you are using. I am using Nginx so I edited the nginx.conf and disabled it.

Comment: Another reason for this error message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416027/invalid-http-post-header-in-django-1-6-2

Comment: @spindel it'd help future users if you provided the solution in your answer.

Comment: How did you disable this in nginx?